# Possibilities to extract at least one ball from a specific color

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I have some comprehension issues regarding combinatorial mathematics.
More specifically, I am asking about advices on how to approach a given problem in combinatorial theories as I feel that these kind of problems rely on logic "intuition" rather than rigorous method.

Let's take an example of an exercise :

Suppose we have a set of 13 balls : 5 red and 8 blue. We take one, we note its color and we put it back in the set. We repeat 4 times the process. So we want to know the number of series in which these conditions are fulfilled :

1. At least, a red ball was extracted.
2. We extract 2 blue and 2 red.

The answer for the first one was :

- Considering that we have a total number of $13^4$ possibilities : we delete the possibilities where we have only blue ones (so $8^4$). We end up with a total of : $13^4 - 8^4$ possibilities for the first case.

I was wrong as I was thinking that : for each red extracted, we can choose $13^3$ possibilities : then I calculated that the total number of possibilities was $5 \cdot 13^3$ : why is it not correct ?

For the second case : I thought we should have $8^2 \cdot 5^2$ but the correct answer was $8^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot C(4,2)$ as I believe $C(4,2)$ refers to a number of choices for each ball but don't understand the reasoning behind it.

If anyone can share some tips about this field and this topic : I would very glad to know and learn from more advanced people here.

Thank you in advance for your help,

Comment: For clarity:  usually in these problem, balls of the same color are treated as indistinguishable.  Therefore, I'd have said there was only $1$ way to choose all Blue...namely $BBBB$.  It appears, however, that you mean something non-standard.  For instance you may want to say that there are $5$ red balls numbered $r_1$ through $r_5$, and $8$ blue balls, $b_1$ through $b_8$.  If that's what you want, though, you should state it explicitly.